# How to copy MySQL Database from Linux to Windows?

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, mysqldump

I would like to copy a MySQL database form Linux to Windows, from a little research I found this url http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-mysql-database-remote-server.html where the author says we could copy MySQL Database using the following command in Linux

**Linux to Linux**

```
mysqldump -u username -p 'password' db-name | ssh user@remote.box.com mysql -u username -p 'password' db-name
```

Is there a command for copying MySQL database from Linux to Windows?

Comment: Do you mean on the same machine?

Comment: dump db on one server, import dump on other server: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: It means from a remote server via ssh console....you can do it in any of the pc with an ssh-console enabled

Comment: @RoneyMichael from a Linux Machine to a Windows Machine

Comment: @MarcB thanks you, I do know this but is there a single command to do this from Linux to Windows just like from Linux Machine to an other Remote Linux Machine?

Answer (score 2):

Linux -> Windows you have two obvious options.

1. Setup a SSHD on your Windows machine and use the above command (mysql binary would need to be in your search path under Windows).
2. Configure your root (or similar privileged account) to access your Windows MySQL host over network then do:

`mysqldump -u username -p 'password' db-name | mysql -h windowsip -u username -p 'password' db-name`

Unfortunately with #2, if you have complex indicies (or huge tables) you'll have issues with `net_read_timeout` on your Linux host. For most situations I would expect this to just work, though.